# set system vpn (pptp vpn) in selenium headless option

Tags: python, selenium, automation, proxy, vpn

I have a system VPN (I am using pptp protocol) and I am going to use Selenium to test our website, but since only internal users are able to access that website without using a VPN, I cannot access the website to test. When I am using Selenium in GUI mode (not headless) it works fine without any problems but when I switch to headless mode using this command:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I get an error because my VPN does not work in the headless mode. Is there any way to use and set my VPN in headless mode in Selenium?